# Why doesn't Hibernate work any more (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I am having a problem with Hibernating my Windows 7 PC. When ever I try to hibernate, the screen goes blank for a while, there's disk activity and then I am presented with the Login Screen.

I've tried enabling/disabling hibernation, not helped.
When I run `shutdown /h` I get a error: "The system cannot find the file specified.(2)"

I've checked and "hiberfil.sys" does exist.

How can I get hibernation working again?

**EDIT:** Just ran `shutdown /h` and monitored it with Process Monitor (something I should have done at the beginning) and the only file it cannot find is "C:\Windows\rescache\rc0008":

```
08:10:24.6198561 AM shutdown.exe    3684    CreateFile  C:\Windows\rescache\rc0008  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

I went to "C:\Windows\rescache" and saw:

```
rc0006 (Folder)

rc0007 (Folder)

ResCache.mni (File)
```

Now I tried just copying rc0007 and rename it to rc0008 but I get a access denied error (even when running as Administrator). Should I bother going into safe mode and copying and renaming rc0007 to rc0008. Will it help? Does this shed some light on the problem?

Comment: Do you use original Windows 7? I mean.. loaders and mods can cause this. A lot of people were talking about such problems and finally I found out that their loader ruined it. (Just an idea, no offense.)

Comment: No, none that I know of. Is there a way to tell if there is one installed (I'm thinking a virus/another user...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem. On the "advice" from a friend, I set the active partition from the 100mb "System" to C:. Restarted, "Windows Boot Manager Failed to Load Windows". Inserted installation DVD and select "Repair your Computer". When it was searching OS's it came up and said I had a boot manager problem and do I want to repair it? I did and Windows loaded. I can now hibernate! I can also see Windows 7 listed in the “Start-up and Recovery” Options (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/154931/why-is-windows-7-not-listed-in-start-up-and-recovery-options)). Windows boots instantly and is actually a lot snappier! I have no idea how this could have helped, but it did. The only problem is that the Windows Boot Screen is the old "Vista" style (i.e. just a progress bar at the bottom), so anyone knows how to fix this, then please say.

Comment: I don't understand you friend's advice to change the partition marked as "active" (bootable). This strikes me as a kludge to force "Repair your Computer". You should have been able to boot the Win 7 install DVD and "Repair your Computer" without mucking around with your partitions. Oh, well.

Answer (score 14):

Because your system partition is not active anymore.

Click start - right click "Computer" - click "Manage" - go to Storage - Disk Management - Right Click Windows Partition And "Mark Partition As Active".

Comment: I use Linux in dual boot with Windows, it didn't even cross my mind that changing the active partition caused the issue. Interesting issue.

Answer (score 6):

Try recreating the hibernate file:

1. Open cmd.exe in admin mode, by typing cmd in start menu and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter
2. Type `powercfg -h off`
3. Type `powercfg -h on`

Check if you can hibernate now.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. Tried running "shutdown /h" again and got "The system cannot find the file specified.(2)"...

Comment: Was there any error when you tried to turn -h off or -h on?

Comment: No, there were no errors (there was actually no output at all). I also ran "sfc /scannow", but still not working...

Comment: Have just done a System Restore: still nothing

Comment: Did this start happenning after you did something specific?

Comment: Not really. I just tried to hibernate and couldn't. What I don't understand is that I used to hibernate before and all went fine. I haven't installed any programs for a while, so I don't know what could be causing it. Now I am beginning to consider sending it in for repair or doing a re-installation/repair from the Windows Disc. Can you still do a System Repair as I couldn't see that option when booting the install DVD (apart from "Repair your Computer" which is not the same as the option on my old XP Disc.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem:

```
>shutdown /h
The system cannot find the file specified.(2)
```

My solution was enabling *automount* via *diskpart.exe:*

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: FELIX-T420SI

DISKPART> automount

Automatic mounting of new volumes disabled.

DISKPART> automount enable

Automatic mounting of new volumes enabled.

DISKPART>
```

Following a restart, hibernation now works.