# Windows 7 will not hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't Hibernate work any more (Windows 7)?](https://superuser.com/questions/155308/why-doesnt-hibernate-work-any-more-windows-7)

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. When I put my laptop in hibernate mode, it turns off then turns back on automatically in the next moment.

I restored the computer to factory settings and it seemed to fix the problem at the time, but after a week I am facing this issue again. I have updated my video driver and also checked the BIOS. This is a recurring problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a quote from [a user-supplied answer on another Q&A site that is hosted by Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-wont-sleep-or-hibernate/208de011-3792-4e12-8368-6c67381186e2):

> Hi, this may be due to wakeon lan feature, Please turn it off and check
>
> To turn power management features on or off
>
> 1. Open Network and Sharing Center
>      (click the Start button, type **Network and Sharing** in the Start Search box, and press Enter).
> 2. Click the **Change adapter settings** link in the upper left of the navigation pane.
> 3. Right click the network connection you want to enable/disable power management support on
>      and click **Properties**.
> 4. Click Configure.
> 5. On the **Power Management** tab,
>      check or clear the **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power** check box.
>
>    - When checked, power management is enabled on the network adapter.
>    - When cleared, power management is disabled on the network adapter.
> 6. You can enable Wake on LAN for all wake methods or just enable magic packet WoL:
>
>    - To enable Wake on LAN for all methods,
>        check the **Allow this device to wake the computer** check box.
>    - To enable Wake on LAN for magic packet only,
>        check the **Allow this device to wake the computer** check box
>        and then check **Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer** check box.
>    - **NOTE** - For devices that do not support ARP and NS offloads,
>        Windows will default to wake only on magic packet.
> 7. Click **OK**.