# Windows 7 Won't Hibernate after Windows Update, Wakes Solved

Tags: sleep, hibernate

I had a windows 7 system that hibernated every single day of my life, except on the days- Windows forced a critical update to my computer.  Then I always had to do a system restore to get back hibernation back and working properly, then manually go to Windows update and download/install the updates myself. That method of manually installing the updates never caused a problem for me to be able to hibernate.   But system restore was critical every single time after Microsoft installed the critical update to enable hibernation again.

Long story short I had no restore points to go back to. There was a forcded Windows update and I lost hibernation.  I spent the better part of 7 weeks, day and night, night and day CHANGING EVERYTHING ON MY COMPUTER to get back hibernation.  Nothing worked.

I MEAN I CHANGED EVERYTHING in no particular order.

- I updated every single driver I had, over 25.
- I updated the bios.
- I checked to see that I had sleep/hibernation capability in the bios.
- I downloaded and installed and ran Drivermax, Tuneup Utilities, Driverbooster, Boostspeed, Slimdrivers, numerous programs aimed at being a substitute for hibernation, Intel drivers, Realtek drivers
- I shut off every single possible device in device manager by disabling them. still no hibernate.
- I unchecked every box in device manager to allow my computer to sleep.
- I ran powerconfig.exe - energy many many times, followed all those leads for weeks.
- I deleted scheduled tasks that might be a problem, windows media,mcupdate etc.
- I shut off my own Fios router.
- I unjoined my windows 7 wireless home group.
- I checked and unchecked hundreds of times the options in Power Plans.  I even changed power plans many times.
- I used many registry cleaners.
- I ran several Microsoft Hotfixes aimed to solve the power problem.
- I ran the system readiness tool. Some of these things I was just guessing.
- I ran sfc /scannow many times because it kept stopping at less than 100% or would complete very fast like as if it hadn't worked.
- I ran my Windows 7 System Repair Disc, to repair and it said my computer is booting, nothing to fix.
- I rolled back drivers.
- I ran Windows Hotfixes, Mr. Fix its, to fix Windows Update because by this time it was offering the same 2 updates over and over again.
- I installed and ran CCCleaner, Wise Care 365., WinUtilities, Glary Utilities.
- I defragged a few times with a few programs, updated drivers on mice, and keypad.
- I ran an online scan with Eset.
- I ran hijack this and checked many items to delete, of which many did not go away. ie "file missing."
- I did so many things in 7 weeks that my mind can't remember them all! Truly. I read and followed at least 100 pages of recommendations.

**Then I solved this problem in 2 ways.** I hesitate to tell you how for fear it will break again for me, but it has been working for 3 days despite several restarts/shut downs and testings throughout the day.

**1.** My computer stopped sleeping, it wouldn't  sleep along the way, when I ran this command or one very similar  powercfg -H -size 100% and PowerCfg.exe /HIBERNATE /SIZE 100, and  it brought back sleep. Sleep was turned on. from sizing my hibernation file. Go Figure.  Still no hibernate!

**2.** Then  The answer was found on this page - [Why doesn't Hibernate work any more (Windows 7)?](https://superuser.com/questions/155308/why-doesnt-hibernate-work-any-more-windows-7)

It appeared like this -

Got the same problem:

> shutdown /h
>   The system cannot find the file specified.(2)

My solution was enabling automount via diskpart.exe:

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: FELIX-T420SI

DISKPART> automount

Automatic mounting of new volumes disabled.

DISKPART> automount enable

Automatic mounting of new volumes enabled.

DISKPART>

Following a restart, hibernation now works.
share|improve this answer

answered Aug 3 at 20:01
feklee
402420

- I had never heard of DISKPART.  I had and have no idea what it does, but I tried it and restarted and IT WORKED.
  I can hibernate.  That is all I did, and in one moment in time with one change I could hibernate windows 7 again. 
  SOLVED.

THANK YOU feklee!

PS Since there are thousands/millions of us with this problem, I wanted to add that this above solution worked for me to the original thread, to add what didn't work for me, and I rarely saw mentioned a direct relationship with Windows update and losing hibernation anywhere on the web with a fix, but the original thread was closed so I posted it this way.

Comment: Please, take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour). Really.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't add "thanks" as questions. You should invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Comment: This question contains a very valid solution. I would protect it instead of marking it as a duplicate.