# Hibernation not working: steps to debug why

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've got a laptop on which hibernation had worked for long time, then it suddenly stopped. On Windows 7, the button hibernate disappeared from the start Menu, if I try to force the hybernation through:

```
 shutdown /h
```

the notebook simply appears to lock the computer.

How do I log what windows is doing? He is aware of the problem where did it wrote the information? Is there any software which can help me at understanding Windows choices?

Comment: Please explain the downvotes or your account will be banned for lack of effort!! (it would be a wonderful world if this would happen.. :-p)

Comment: Echoing the OP: Please explain the downvote. The question is well-formed and on-topic for Super User. (+1 from me.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a great answer in a question which is duplicated and not correct for the rules of this community. But however it's the only I could find which solve the problem.

[Windows 7 Won't Hibernate after Windows Update, Wakes Solved](https://superuser.com/questions/802911/windows-7-wont-hibernate-after-windows-update-wakes-solved)

I solved by simply writing:

```
cmd

powercfg -h on

powercfg -h -size 100
```

`shutdown /h` now works, the button is still not visible but it's ok.

Some other adviced steps taken from forums:

1. Disable/enable hibernation using powercfg -h tool
2. Change hibernation file size to 100% of amount of RAM (powercfg -h size 100)
3. Run deep CHKDSK during system boot
4. Run deep antyvirus scan using Avast 4.8 (in boot mode)
5. Check system logs. All (maybe) usable information I found was - Application and Services Log -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Kernel-Power -> Thermal -> Working of processor 0 (or 1) was reduced by process different than kernel power manager (ID:91).
6. Check running processes to find any strange or suspicious.

sfc /scannow. This scans for bad system files, and repairs them if necessary.

If that does not work, perhaps a Repair Install

Check also this possible solutions:

a) Allow this computer to turn of this device to preserve power consumption
b) Allow this device to resume computer from standby

Option a) MUST be enabled for computer to be able to hibernate/standby because ALL devices must be compatible to EnergyStar standard to allow computer to hibernate

althrough....

Option b) allows computer to wake up via "Wake Up on LAN" or Magic Packet (as some call it).

**At the end I solved by restoring my plan setting here:**
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options