# Windows 7 installation loses volume label after reboot if no drive letter assigned

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Here is my problem:

I have had a Dell laptop with the following partitions:

```
39 MB - (OEM Partition);
14 GB, label: RECOVERY, no drive letter;
200 GB, label: OS, drive letter C:
```

I used the "Minitool" partition manager to copy everything to a new larger disk.

After that, the partitions looked like:

```
39 MB - (OEM Partition);
14 GB, label: (RECOVERY), no drive letter;
300 GB, label: OS, drive letter C:
```

Windows didn't show the volume label of the second partition although it is still there, showing in gparted or testdisk.

In this state the following other problems exist:

1. Hibernation doesn't work -
   [How to diagnose failure to hibernate after hard drive swap (yet sleep works fine)?](https://superuser.com/questions/98380/how-to-diagnose-failure-to-hibernate-after-hard-drive-swap-yet-sleep-works-fine)
2. Windows not listed as default operating system -
   [Why is Windows 7 not listed in "Start-up and Recovery" Options](https://superuser.com/questions/154931/why-is-windows-7-not-listed-in-start-up-and-recovery-options)
3. EasyBCD fails to retrieve the boot information
4. If I try to change the drive letter in the disk management console (diskmgmt.msg) I get
   the message: "The volume label is not valid. Please enter a valid
   volume label."

If I assign a drive letter to the second partition,
    for example R:, it all becomes good: Hibernation works again,
    Windows shows up as default operating system, EasyBCD works.

Now the clou:
If I remove the drive letter again, the label doesn't get hidden and everything keeps on working ... until the next reboot.

Upon reboot, all goes back to square one, the volume label doesn't show and the various things mentioned don't work any more.

This is what I've tried to fix the problem:

1. Windows Startup Repair, including a bootrec /fixboot
2. Checked access
   rights (secutity tab) to the volumes: SYSTEM has full access as it
   should be
3. Checked HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
   Manager\BootExecute for left-overs of the disk clone
4. Cleaned up
   HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices\
5. Used EasyBCD to check boot configuration
6. In fact, I compared all this to another
   Dell with the same partition setup that doesn't show the problem.

I'm at the end of my wisdom, please help!

Answer (score 0):

if you have done **copy everything to a new larger disk.**
now you can use dell recover default factory:

1. Turn on / restart Dell laptop.
2. At the time of its Dell logo appears, press the **Ctrl** key in conjunction with the **F11** key.
3. The Dell PC Restore menu screen will automatically appear.
4. Select "Restore" or use the Tab key to sign / highlight it and press .
5. Click the "Confirm", or use the Tab key to sign / highlight it and press .
6. When the utility is finished, click "Finish".

Comment: The answer is besides the point. Of course a reinstall will solve any problem.